# Office365 SMTP server extremely slow from Thunderbird on Linux

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, smtp

I've been using Thunderbird on Linux to access the Office365 email account of my company. Starting from last week, connections suddenly became extremely slow. I regularly wait for 3 to 5 minutes before I'm able to send out a simple text email, and during this time Thunderbird just says "Connecting to outlook.office365.com..." However, if I access the same email account on the web using outlook.office.com, opening and sending emails are instant.

Has anyone encountered similar problems before? Is the problem likely to be with my ISP, my email client (Thunderbird), or Microsoft's servers?

Comment: Are you using` IMAP` perchance? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/osecurity-oother/imap-xoauth2-login-failure-several-clients/3ad3b3f9-77c2-4239-b168-1af5a3bbb6b9?messageId=4c916654-b310-432e-9011-f00653f5c485&auth=1

Comment: I use both IMAP (for receiving) and SMTP (for sending). Both became extremely slow last week. Thanks for the link. Will take a closer look.

Comment: What happens if you use other mail applications(e.g. Native app or outlook) to access your office 365 email account? What about other clients such as windows 7/10, mac, mobile devices and so on?